# Canon irADV-C3525i is not printing though drivers are installed

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, canon

So let's clarify, I have already installed the drivers a number of times, I have used CQUE, I have used CUPS and everything seems fine. In addition to this, the printer has been picked up on "Wifi" it is attached to the right IP address, but when I try to print out from it, it doesn't bring up an Authentication prompt like in Windows.

JUST TO CLARIFY, I AM NOT ADMIN. I have no access to the configuration of the printer itself. My credentials and stuff are on the printer already. By this, I mean that I have a username and password to use it. However, I am not getting the Authentication prompt that I need, so the printer just disregards the requests.

Answer (score 0):

when I look on the Canon site, they recommend their **UFR** driver; that was released 8th Feb 2018 as the right driver. http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html and it comes down as **linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz**
 so to install the commands would be

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz
cd linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken
sudo ./install.sh
```

sounds like your are happy with the other driver but I thought to mention what Canon would recommend